# Why don't the birds get the bracha of פְּרוּ?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, parashat-bereishit, birds

In the creation of the world when Hashem is creating fish and birds, the verse in Beresheit 1:22 says,"וַיְבָ֧רֶךְ אֹתָ֛ם אֱלֹהִ֖ים לֵאמֹ֑ר **פְּר֣וּ וּרְב֗וּ** וּמִלְא֤וּ אֶת־הַמַּ֙יִם֙ בַּיַּמִּ֔ים וְהָע֖וֹף **יִ֥רֶב** בָּאָֽרֶץ׃, "God blessed them, saying, **“Be fertile and increase**, fill the waters in the seas, and let the birds **increase** on the earth.”
My question is, it seems that fish get the blessing of פְּר֣וּ וּרְב֗וּ but the birds only get יִ֥רֶב (from same root as וּרְבוּ), so why is that? What differentiates the birds from the fish?

Creative ideas with sources are welcomed :)

Comment: the Alschich discusses this https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.22?lang=bi&with=Alshich&lang2=en

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 2):

Interesting to note that the שיטה מקובצת כתובות דף ה עמוד א points out that the reason why the Gemara there write's that newlywed's should have relations on Thursday, is because of the ברכה של דגים was on Thursday, and the Gemara didn't pick ברכה של עופות is because of your differentiation that by the ברכה of birds it only says ורבו.

However he doesn't provide any reason why it's so. Perhaps we can explain that because fish aren't effected by the evil eye (see Berachos 20a), therefore they can multiply more aggressively then the birds, and that is why when one gets married he does so on Thursday, so that he can achieve the unique blessing of fish that besides being able to have children we want to be protected from the evil eye as well..

Comment: Nice connection, however I don't see how it answers the question...